# docker build python with lxml, wheel build fails

Tags: docker, build, raspberry-pi, lxml

I am unable to build a docker container with `sudo docker-compose up --build` that will build with lxml.

Image: Tried the following with no luck:
ubuntu, python3.9.5-buster-lite, python3.9.5

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mycoolapp:
    container_name: 'coolapp'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.coolapp
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Here is my docker file (My requirements.txt has "lxml" listed with no version):

```
# pull official base image                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
FROM python:3.9.6-buster                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#This is for lxml                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y python3-lxml                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
COPY requirements.txt /                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                         
COPY . /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ENTRYPOINT ["./gunicorn_starter.sh"]
```

Asside from trying `apt-get install -y python3-lxml` in my above Dockerfile.coolapp, I also tried the following with no success, all from lxml's [website](https://lxml.de/installation.html).

```
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y gcc libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev                                                                                                                                                               
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y gcc g++ libxml2-dev libxslt-dev                                                                                                                                                                      
RUN pip3 install lxml
```

docker version: Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
The build is being performed on a raspberry pi 2b, its old. The system has 948308kb (~1GB) of memory, so its slow.

Error: I get the following two errors every time I try to build.

```
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-luxzc2gm
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/
  Complete output (81 lines):
  Building lxml version 4.6.3.
  Building without Cython.
  Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.32
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src/lxml
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -w
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,--strip-all build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -L/usr/local/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lrt -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/etree.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
Successfully built bs4 MarkupSafe
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: soupsieve, MarkupSafe, Werkzeug, urllib3, Jinja2, itsdangerous, idna, click, chardet, certifi, beautifulsoup4, requests, lxml, gunicorn, Flask, bs4
    Running setup.py install for lxml: started
    Running setup.py install for lxml: still running...
    Running setup.py install for lxml: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4c9_up7a/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/lxml
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/
    Complete output (81 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.6.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.32
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/html
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src/lxml
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -w
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,--strip-all build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -L/usr/local/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lrt -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/lxml/etree.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-32cu6b3q/lxml_75dfbf51995e40dd9829fd90df4669cf/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4c9_up7a/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/lxml Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I should also note that if I try to build it on my other linux box, I do not run into issues, not sure why.

The errors is not straight forward. Reading online wheel may fail if the system runs out of memory, is that true? Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Had to use a newer python image. Using `FROM python3.9.6-buster` in my Dockerfile.coolapp finally built.